# How to show a specific tab after login?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs

I have a tabcontroller with 5 different tabs. I log out from the 5th tab and the login view controller appears as a push segue. When I login again, I set it up to pop the login view a show the root controller which is the 5th tab I mentioned before. What I would like to achieve is that after the user is logged in successfully, the first tab is shown instead of the 5th tab view.

I have tried with [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:] method but the first tab view appears without tab bar. I also tried to set on the first tab view [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO] but it does not work.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that, if your RootViewController is a NavigationController and not the UITabBarController, you're setting the selectedIndex of your UITabBarController in the RootViewController of your Application like this:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
```

If you're on another ViewController and can't access your RootViewController you may send a local notification through NSNotificationCenter like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"LoginHasCompleted" object: nil];
```

and add a Observer to your RootViewController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(switchToIndexNumber) name: @"LoginHasCompleted" object: nil];
```

Answer (score -2):

the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
will probably answer your question.

I was able to successfully switch the view controller to the correct tab using the following code.  I hope this helps.

[(UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController setSelectedIndex:4];

Of course you should change the selected index to 0 if you want the first tab to load.